# how to automatically add IP address to list of known host when ssh?

Tags: bash, ssh

**Situation**

Two systems. One which add IP address automatically to list of known host when doing ssh.

```
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.158.XXX' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

One which doesn't

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
9c:79:39:54:44:20:bd:65:19:93:5b:00:bb:b7:9c:0c.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /home/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts:14
  remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/home/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 192.168.158.XXX
Password authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
Keyboard-interactive authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
```

**Problem**

How to set the second system to do it automatically? It's for internal tests, I know it would be dangerous else.

Comment: Just delete ./ssh/known_hosts file on the machine that remembers the old key.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Remote host identification has changed" warning when connecting over SSH](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9800/remote-host-identification-has-changed-warning-when-connecting-over-ssh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other would automatically add too, but it doesn't because it already has a matching entry with a different key. I usually turn off checking using `StrictHostKeyChecking` (and deleting `known_hosts` if I get too annoyed, you may need to manually recreate it if, for some reason, it doesn't get automatically create a new `known_hosts`):

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no host
```

You may need to set `CheckHostIP` too (`-o CheckHostIP=no`).

Comment: I made many tries, like this one
bash -c 'timeout 300s ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o CheckHostIP=no root@192.168.158.93 "mkdir -p NightTest"'
but still the same error...

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim Delete your `known_hosts` and try again.

Comment: I found lot's of way to delete a particular host, but is there a way to delete them all?

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim yes: delete the file.

Comment: I deleted it and now every ssh command just do nothing (command is waiting for timeout)

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim I cannot reproduce that. I test out the exact command you gave me, with hostnames changed, and they work fine for me.

Comment: Once deleted .ssh/known_hosts it would not recreate itself. I copied another one and now it works fine! Thanks. However is it a normal comportment?

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim It *should* recreate itself.

Comment: I see! I marked your answer as the answer, but if you don't mind I'd add a note to keep a known_hosts copy in case it doesn't recreate (I was really lucky that I made one before).

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim if it doesn't a recreate itself, that's a problem to be looked into as well. If not, just `touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts`. Edit in a note, I'll approve it.